# deserialize json with dynamic property name

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

i need deserialize this json (https://mtgjson.com/json/AllCards.json), but have property name dynamic, y try with json.net with dynamic object in c#. help please.

Comment: Can we have a look at your code? Just the block where you do your deserialization.

Comment: var listas = new List<string>();

            string cartasJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\AllCards.json");
            var cartas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(cartasJson);

            foreach (var item in cartas)
            {
                listas.Add(item.name);
            }





Whe i try to get name property, the program crash because dont find the "name" property

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3806407/1399272).  You can use something like the following:

```
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path/to/dataFile.json"); // read JSON string data
dynamic data = Json.Decode(json); // parse JSON string
```

You will need to get `Json.Decode` from the `System.Web.Helpers` assembly, which I think should be available in the [MVC 5 Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/).